# ExtJS4: Form fieldset listener

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have ExtJS4 form, and [FieldSet](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.FieldSet) there. Fieldset is being controller by CHECKBOX. I need to listen that checkbox change event.

```
{
                    xtype:"fieldset",
                    width:440,
                    padding:5,
                    title:"1st break",
                    layout:"hbox",
                    name:"irest_first",
                    checkboxToggle:true,
                    items:[{
                        xtype:"timefield",
                        fieldLabel:"something",
                        margin:"0 5 0 0",
                        width:120,
                        labelWidth:30
                    },{
                        xtype:"timefield",
                        fieldLabel:"something",
                        margin:"0 5 0 0",
                        width:120,
                        labelWidth:30                            
                    }]
                }
```

What listener I need to use? tried collapse and expand, not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sencha removed events for collapse/expand from ExtJs4. They are putting them back in 4.1. If you're using 4.0.x you will have to override collapse method yourself.